# Fatal error using orfeo toolbox (otb 8.0.0) algorithm Computeconfusionmatrix in QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis-3, python-3, image-classification, otb-applications, confusion-matrix

I tried to compute a confusion matrix of a raster classification with otb's Computeconfusionmatrix using vector data (polygons) as reference input. When I run the same algorithm in mapla (otb standalone) it produces an error matrix CSV file. When I run it in QGIS environment, from processing toolbox directly and in QGIS model builder, I always get the same error:

> (FATAL) ComputeConfusionMatrix: itk::ERROR: FieldParameter(0000014FD6BF7670): Single selection mode is on, but there are 2 selected items

Has anybody received the same error or any idea what it means? Maybe a Python issue?

Or either: Does somebody know an alternative to compute a confusion matrix using raster/vector input? SAGA provided something like this in QGIS but the new version 3.22 does not support the last SAGA version.

Processing protocol:

```
{ 'in' : 'C:/*/Tob13_class2.tif', 
  'out' : 'C:/*/Tob13_confi14.csv', 
  'format' : 'confusionmatrix', 
  'ref' : 'vector', 
  'ref.vector.in' : 'C:/*/Tob_13_TS_train_split2.shp', 
  'ref.vector.field' : 'Class nr', 
  'ref.vector.nodata' : None, 
  'nodatalabel' : 0 }
```

Error log:

> 2022-04-13 12:21:46 (FATAL) ComputeConfusionMatrix: itk::ERROR:
> FieldParameter(0000014FD6BF7670): Single selection mode is on, but
> there are 2 selected items Execution completed in 0.11 Sekunden
> Ergebnisse: 'out': 'C:/*/Tob13_confi14.csv'}